# Number of 3-subsets in which an element of a set $S$ appears in if every pair of elements in $S$ appears in exactly two of it's 3-subsets, together.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The actual statement of the problem roughly translates into: "A total of $n$ people are forming committees of size 3, such that every two of them are in exactly 2 of these committees, together. How many committees is each person, a member of?"

I'm having issues starting, I tried thinking that for every arbitrary pair of elements $a, b$ there should be exactly two subsets of size 3. I tried counting the number of subsets but that didn't really get me anywhere either. I probably need a fresh point of view and that's what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are $\,\binom{n}{2}\,$ pairs of people, each pair has to be on exactly two committees, and there are exactly three possible pairs of people per committee, that means the number of committees has to be

$$\frac{2\binom{n}{2}}{3}= \frac{n(n-1)}{3}$$

That means that the total number of committee members is $\,n(n-1),\,$ and since there are only $\,n\,$ people, each person must be on $\,n-1\,$ committees.

Comment: There are 3 people in total per committee, not three pairs of people.

Comment: You're right, my wording was unclear; what I meant was that there are exactly three **possible** pairs; e.g. if a committee is made up of persons A, B and C, the three possible pairs would be (A,B), (A,C) and (B,C). I've corrected the wording in my solution.

Comment: Are we not over counting then?

Comment: We would be, that's why the calculation includes the division by three.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, does this mean if $n(n-1)$ is not divisible by 3 people forming of committees with the conditions above is impossible? I can't see why that would be.

Comment: Yes, it does indicate that if $\,n \equiv 2\pmod 3,\,$ no solutions are possible. The case $\,n=2\,$ is trivial, and if you try it is not difficult to see that there no solution for $\,n=5.\,$ However, I can't think of a way, other than the above solution itself, to show that the general $\,n \equiv 2\pmod 3\,$ case is impossible.